# Formatting numbers after coloring a dataframe using Styler

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting, pandas-styles

I created a DataFrame in pandas for which I want to color the cells using a color index (low values red, high values green). I succeeded in doing so, however the coloring prevents me to format the cells.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.5,1.5, 5],
                   'b': [2, 3.5, 7] })

df = df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn')
df
```

which returns

[image]

However, when I try to use `df.round(2)` for example to format the numbers, the following error pops up:

`AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'round'`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at the [pandas styling guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html). The `df.style` property returns a `Styler` instance, not a dataframe. From the examples in the pandas styling guide, it seems like dataframe operations (like rounding) are done first, and styling is done last. There is [a section on precision](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Formatting-Values) in the pandas styling guide. That section proposes three different options for displaying precision of values.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.5,1.5, 5],
                   'b': [2, 3.5, 7] })

# Option 1. Round before using style.
style = df.round(2).style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn')
style

# Option 2. Use option_context to set precision.
with pd.option_context('display.precision', 2):
    style = df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn')
style

# Option 3. Use .format() method of styler.
style = df.style.format(precision=2).background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn')
style
```

Comment: Option 1 doesn't work for me, but 2 and 3 are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to hear it. If this answer solved your problem, please click the green check mark to mark it as correct.

Comment: Method '.set_precision' is deprecated in the current Pandas release (v1.3.1). The new method passes float precision through '.format(precision = 2)'. However, I had a problem with this and had to revert to previous Pandas version. I tried various methods as stated in the docs, but I couldn't get it to work. Perhaps an inconsistency with the older Python version I use 3.7.7.

Comment: Option 1 does not work, Option 3 works. Thanks

Comment: thanks @TrentonMcKinney I have updated the answer to fix this.

Comment: You might want to just delete 3. As the other answer already covers `.format`. In any case, also update the docstring for #3 if you leave it.

Answer (score 1):

This works with me:

```
stylish_df = df.style.background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn').format(precision=2)
```